# Unsupervised learning to separate two groups

Tags: machine-learning, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I am currently working on a passenger noise separation of a public transportation system. I only have unlabeled data which means I can not do supervised learning.

The data consist of the MAC address detection, locations, and times...

I handle the data and make them into four features

I have four features like the number of detection of MAC for each identical MAC address, the distance for each identical MAC traveled, the duration of each MAC, and the speed of each MAC.

I have tried KMeans clustering, the result seems to be ok.

1. I am not sure which learning method I should use to best separate the two noise from passengers?
2. What is the best way to evaluate the model?

Comment: Usual clustering approaches, K-means, non/hierarchical clustering, Gaussian Mixture Models, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think K-Means is a reasonable learning method for the clustering exercise you're alluding to.  Depending on what you're trying to accomplish (like, perhaps, finding outliers), I would also consider looking at using STL if you have this data in a time series.